# Adding a link to notebook 2 in a notebook 1

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink

How to add a link to open a notebook2 with any name in a notebook1
I tried with `Hyperlink` without success.

Comment: Insert -> Hyperlink works fine here. Can you describe what you have done exactly, and how it failed?

Comment: I use insert and Hyperlink than I browse to my file. In the notebook1, I get the name of the notebook2 (the name of file). I want to change this name with any sentence.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAHyperlink.html

Comment: Try selecting some text before you click on Insert > Hyperlink. Such selected text becomes the label for the hyperlink.

Comment: Yes, this work. Thank you